# Lengths of edges of a triangulated surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, surfaces

Consider a triangulated surface of genus $g,$ which is embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$.  A simple parameter counting shows that the lengths of edges of the surface satisfy $6g$ algebraic equations. Have these relations been studied? Is there a way to write them down?